# Splitting $\mathbb{R}^n$ into two subspaces

Tags: euclidean-geometry, connectedness, dimension-theory-analysis

Does a plane in a more than $3$-dimensional space split it into two connected components?

If not, what is the dimension of subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ which splits it into two connected components? Is it $\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your guess is right, it's $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.

Given a $n-1$-dimensional subspace $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$, there exists a linear functional $f\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that $\ker f = V$.
In that way, $V$ splits $\mathbb R^n$ in two connected components, namely $V_+ = \{x\in\mathbb R^n : f(x) > 0 \}$ and $V_- = \{x\in\mathbb R^n : f(x) < 0 \}$.

Comment: Although it’s conceivable that a lower-dimensional subspace could do the job. But if $V \cong R^k$ is a subspace of $R^n$, then $R^n / V \cong R^{n-k}$, and we can find a path in $R^{n-k}$ that avoids $\vec{0}$ connecting any two points, as long as $n-k > 1$, giving a path in $R^n$ avoiding $V$. That’s the idea, at least.